# Existe-t-il un mot pour le niveau entre intermédiaire et avancé?

Tags: choix-de-mot, vocabulaire

En gros je me débrouille pas mal: je maitrise les bases et ai une bonne idée de ce qu'il me reste à apprendre.
Pour autant, j'ai des connaissances qui dépassent le niveau intermédiaire considéré *standard* dans plusieurs domaines.

Intermédiaire confirmé et semi-avancé ne veulent rien dire.

Comment: Avancé n'est pas non plus le niveau le plus élevé, je mettrais "expert" au niveau encore au-dessus.

Comment: Pourquoi pas passer le [TCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_de_connaissance_du_fran%C3%A7ais) et mettre ta note sur ton CV ?

Comment: @Brenn je n'ai jamais parlé de CV (ni du français en particulier d'ailleurs). Cette question se voulait générale.

Comment: @ℝaphink t'inquiète jle sais bien mais dans mon cas c'est la gradation inférieure qui m'importe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Si c'est pour un CV, j'utiliserais *confirmé*, tout simplement. Ce mot retranscrit l'idée que le niveau de compétences est validé (confirmé) par l'expérience.

---

*Bon niveau* est une autre option que je lis souvent dans ce contexte.

Comment: "niveau confirmé" me parait pompeux et éloigné du sens d'un "je ne suis pas encore à un niveau suffisant bien que dépassant la moyenne". Je vais attendre d'autres propositions.

Comment: "niveau confirmé" n'est pas pompeux du tout AMHA. "bon niveau" est une autre option.

Comment: L'interprétation de ces adjectifs est de toute manière très subjective. Si tu as peur qu'« avancé » soit un terme trop fort pour décrire tes compétences, utilise intermédiaire et laisse-les découvrir que tu vaux juste un peu mieux que ce qu'ils peuvent (peut-être) entendre par « intermédiaire »...

Comment: @raph malheureusement dans mon cas "*seulement* intermédiaire" serait vraiment dévalorisant…

Comment: *bon niveau* semble étrangement convenir: décrit un niveau respectable tout en étant assez galvaudé de nos jours pour ne pas décevoir.

Answer (score 4):

Je ne crois pas qu'il existe un mot précis pour le niveau au-dessus d'intermédiaire, mais au-dessous d'avancé. Personnellement, j'opterais probablement pour "intermédiaire-avancé", ce qui, d'après-moi, indique un niveau supérieur au premier, mais inférieur au deuxième.

Après quelques rapides recherches, l'Université Laval de Québec utilise cette terminologie pour au moins un de ses certificats en langue française (http://www.elul.ulaval.ca/sgc/pid/8468). L'Université de Montréal l'utilise également pour un de ses cours d'anglais (http://www.progcours.umontreal.ca/guichets/progcours/cours/index_fiche_cours/ANG1994.html).

Comment: J'aurais voulu éviter ce genre de mot-composé […] mais il semble que je vais devoir m'y résigner.

Answer (score 4):

Je serais tenté d'étendre ta proposition *Intermédiaire confirmé et semi-avancé ne veulent rien dire*. aux mots *intermédiaire* et *avancé* eux-même, qui a mon sens ne veulent pas dire grand-chose de plus.

En cela, je veux dire qu'ils ne sont pas quantifiables. Bien entendu, on se doute qu'un *expert* est plus qu'*avancé*, et on peut relativement facilement comparer les adjectifs les uns aux autres, mais aucun ne donne vraiment une indication précise du niveau.

Si la discipline le permet, il vaut mieux se fier aux tests et gradations établies: ceintures de judo, points ELO aux échecs, tests de langues comme comme le mentionne Vincent ([TCF](http://www.ciep.fr/en/tcf/) en français, [TOEFL](http://www.ets.org/toefl/) en anglais,...).

Faute de telles quantifications reconnues, j'aurais tendance à éviter l'usage de mots et à lui préférer une échelle numérique, de préférence pas trop étendue (*Sur une échelle de 1 (débutant) à 5 (expert), j'évaluerais ma connaissance de prolog à 2*). C'est aussi facile à mettre en tableau.

Pour moi, les mots ne peuvent pas représenter de manière adéquate une grande échelle de valeurs, et j'en limiterais l'usage à des cas où le nombre de possibilités est limité (4 ou 5). Vouloir en mettre plus ne sert qu'à compliquer les choses inutilement.

Comment: Jusqu'à ce que je le lise "bon niveau" ne m'était pas paru évident. Son usage excessif en fait un choix parfait car totalement subjectif mais néanmoins conservant son sens premier. Il y a de nombreuses disciplines où les tests/gradations n'existent pas et dans ces cas là je ne conseillerais pas une échelle numérique sur 5 car toutes les notes en dessous de 3 ne valent même plus la peine d'être donné car révélant des lacunes plus qu'un niveau propre. Au contraire les mots se connotent positivement naturellement (on a tous été débutant un jour alors qu'on ne peux pas s'identifier à un "1").

Answer (score 0):

Si tu nous disais à quelle occasion tu veux utiliser cette expression, ça pourrait nous aider.

Les expressions d'usage sont:

> Intermédiaire avancé
>
> Débutant confirmé

On ne mélange pas les deux.

Ce sont des usages que l'on retrouve au niveau académique et professionnel et qui sont tout à fait naturels.

Comment: Est-ce qu'un « débutant confirmé » est quelqu'un qui s'y connaît moins qu'un « faux débutant » ou qui s'y connaît plus qu'un « simple débutant » ?